# Truncate Text in ul li anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html ,

```
<ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#">python</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Truncate should apply here </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cpp</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">java</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">.net</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is really a long text in this ul </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is another really a long text in this ul </a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to truncate the text in anchor tag , if the length of text is higher than 6 chars.

The output should like ,

```
    python
    Trun..
    c
    cpp
    java
    .net
    This..
    This..
```

How can i do this using Jquery ?

Comment: this can be done with css by giving width and applying overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('ul.test li a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text.length > 6) {
        $(this).text(text.substring(0, 4) + '..')
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ncrU2/)**

---

If you want to use pure CSS then you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis` property:

```
ul.test li a {
    width: 45px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

However, you cannot control the number of limited characters before putting ellipsis using this approach.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ncrU2/1/)**

Comment: that would change the value of the text

Comment: In Felix's defense, that constraint wasn't a part of the question. Not worth a down vote.  The fact that the OP asked how to do it with jQuery implies otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Try below CSS

```
a {
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W6EWF/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a vanilla JS solution and save some resources (and it's short too):

```
var As = document.getElementsByTagName("a");       // all the `a` elements

for(var  i = 0, len = As.length;i < len; i++){      // iterate over them

    // cut them by 6 characters, and set the new value
    As[i].innerHTML = As[i].innerHTML.substr(0, 6);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/cWvDL/)

Or, you can use the [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property in CSS if you don't want to cut the text and lose it forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following as a start and combine it with some if..else statements to get the desired output.

```
$(".test li a").each(function(index){
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,4)+"...")
})
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S7hhe/)

Another way of doing it using CSS can be found at this JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ues5

Comment: Another way of doing it using CSS can be found at this JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ues5/

Answer (score 0):

**This will do it.**

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
          for (i = 0; i < $("a").length; i++)
            {
               if ($("a")[i].text.length > 6)
                {
                    $("a")[i].text = $("a")[i].text.substring(0,4)+"..";
                }
            }
        });
    });
```